# Can I optimize this IE6 double padding & margin fix by using jQuery selectors/filters instead?

Tags: jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-6, for-loop

Here is some code that I adapted to fix IE6's double padding & margin issue:

```
// Apply double padding & margin fix for IE6
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7) { 

    var elements = self.common.$body.find("*").get();

    for (var i = 0, 
             len = elements.length, 
             $e = $(elements[i]), 
             cssFloat = $e.css("float"), 
             cssDisplay = $e.css("display"); 
         i < len; 
         i++) {

        if (cssDisplay !== "none" && 
           (cssFloat === "left" || cssFloat === "right")) { 
           $e.css("display", "inline"); 
        }

    };

}
```

I was thinking it might be faster to do some sort of `jQuery.filter()` type operation where I would start off by only selecting those elements that didn't have a `display: none;` and that had a `float: left;` or `float: right;`.  Then I could loop through those and simply apply the `display: inline;` fix.

Do you think that would work? If so, what would that selector look like? If not or there is a quicker way, please do let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it not be more practical to just manually add "display:inline" to the CSS where appropriate?

Comment: That's not the question, but to answer you, no, not in my current situation.

Comment: Reason being, I'm in an ASP.NET environment, if JavaScript is disabled, they aren't getting to my site anyway, and I would rather not have to maintain a `display: inline;` everywhere there's a `float: left;` or `float: right;` in our style sheets. This method is fast, as it is.  I just wanted to know if there's a way to filter down the elements before the loop with what my if statement is looking for, rather than looping through ALL elements and checking with the if.

Comment: Yes, that's not your question which is why I posted it as a follow-up comment rather than an answer.  Have you considered this [solution](http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html)?  Yes, while I know it does not answer your original question, you may find it helpful.

Comment: It's a an issue of "jQuery selectors".  How can somebody help you select elements we know little or nothing about?

Comment: You know all you need to know based on the If statement inside of the for loop.  That is the exact filtering of the elements I would need.  You don't need to know anything else?

Comment: If you say so.  If your floating DIVs had some common class, name, id, or hierarchical structure, maybe or maybe not.  But hey, I guess I have no right to ask for more details in order to help you.  Good luck pal.

Comment: No need to get snooty. This question is merely asking if it's possible to improve upon the code I currently have with the filter() method or some other selector. That's all. But, to answer your question, there is no common class, name, id, or structure that would allow for an easy selector as you are suggesting.  If that were the case, I could simply do it in CSS and be done with it.

Comment: You're the one looking for help and getting snippy with the only person trying to offer any assistance.

Comment: Maybe you are reading tone into words.  I'm simply saying I'm not looking to implement another solution for IE6 or IE7.  I was just looking for advice regarding optimizing my solution with jQuery.  I created this method before I implemented jQuery and am now revisiting it and figured there was some other way to that didn't involve looping through every single element in the body.

Comment: I mean I know this solution uses jQuery, but that's because I just updated it to do so and that's why I'm curious if there's a faster way than what I'm currently doing. My answer seems to go in that direction, but I need to test which one is faster.

Comment: You already stated you don't care about people with JavaScript disabled.  I'll bet you even fewer people still use IE 6.  People using IE 6 see worse than double margins all over the place.  To them, your site looks just as bad as the next.  Again, just another helpful comment that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Well this not personal. This is a company who doesn't want to alienate 5-10% of our visitors. Again, this isn't a philosophical question. It's very specific. If you have an applicable answer I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Just curious if you wouldn't mind disclosing what industry still has that many visitors using IE 6.  I honestly have less than 1% visiting my sites.  Although I know it's higher in certain niche markets which is why I ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to create a test case on ***[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/double-padding-margin-ie6-fix)***.

The results seem to favor my original design.  At least that answers the question.  If anyone else has another method, I'd love to see it.